# Numbers triangle?

Tags: javascript, numbers

I am new to programming still trying to apply for an IT academy and learning the basics.
I am limited into using only arrays,strings,loops and conditions.

I have been given a task to print a triangle from 1 to N and below.
Example: 3

```
  1 
  1 2
  1 2 3 
  1 2 
  1
```

I used this:

```
var N = 2,
num = "";

for(var i=1; i<=N; i++)
{
  num = num + i
 console.log(num)}
 for(var j = num.length ; j = 1 ; j--){
 num = num.slice(0, -1)
  console.log(num);
 ;}
```

But it takes more than a second to do, could you please give me some tips on that I would deeply appreciate it!

Edit: Made the second loop right and all worked well. Thank you everybody for the help!

Comment: Your second loop never ends

Comment: Do you need tips only, or a solution?

Comment: I am trying to think and build my own logic so solution is fine as long as it is at least briefly exaplained :) Otherwise tips will do me good :)

Comment: If your solution is working but you are wanting to see if you can improve on it, codereview might be better on the stackexchange site. Just make sure to follow their rules- SO is more for solving specific issues, so I will be voting to close this as too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array with `n` indices and then join then

```js
const N = 3;

for (var i = (-1 * N) + 1; i < N; i++) {
  console.log(Array(N - Math.abs(i)).fill(0).map((i, j) => j + 1).join(' '));
}

//Or
for (var i = (-1 * N) + 1; i < N; i++) {
  console.log([...Array(N - Math.abs(i))].map((i, j) => j + 1).join(' '));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

A solution with only arrays (and array methods), strings, loops and conditions:

```
const N = 3;    
var nr = [];

for (i = 1; i <= N; i++){
  nr.push(i);
  console.log(nr.join(" "));
}

for (i = N; i > 0; i--){
  nr.pop();
  console.log(nr.join(" "));
}
```

Reading tip: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_methods.asp